# MySQL regex validate field value is a domain or subdomain

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-5.5

I am trying to transfer a list of domain names from an old system to a newer one.

The problem is the the data in the old database was used as a reference and contains additional information but the new system will integrate with cpanel and thus the domain has to be correct.

I am trying to automate the import of the old data that does conform to my requirements and leave aside for manual import the ~4% that does not.

I have used a regular expression to achieve this but for some reason it is not working as I expect it.

This is the condition I use:

```
`domain` REGEXP '^[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$' = 1
```

It correctly identifies the following as not being valid:

```
https://test-1.example.com:8443/login_up.php3
118.18.187.15
```

But fails for the wollowing:

```
the-example.com mchannel
example.com NEW
```

I know regex decently well but I can't figure out why in this case it does not work.

Fiddle URL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9d70/5

Example what should validate: http://www.regexr.com/39f4v

Comment: Shouldn't the `$` ensure there is nothing allowed after the domain name?

Comment: $ means: Assert position at the very end of the string.

Comment: Try to use: [[:<:]][\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}[[:>:]]

Comment: I know what it means. I am saying here that without it the regex will allow characters after it, with it it should not. If regex starts with ^ and ends with $ it should ensure the reges is checked against the whole string not parts of it. Thus it is correct to use them. Isn't it?

Comment: @Andie2302 your regex only fails for IP addresses and matches everything else.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should match everything from the first regex and the ips

```
[[:<:]][\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}[[:>:]]|[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+
```

Comment: It is not supposed to identify IPs as valid. Only domains and subdomain. No text, no urls with www, http .. etc.. I mentioned the regex it identifies correctly the IP and URL as not being valid but failed to invalidate those with strings at the end. Only the following should be validated. http://www.regexr.com/39f4v